# Selenium find_element_by_css_selector to fire before the page has fully loaded

Tags: python, selenium, testing, webdriver, performance-testing

I have a basic python script to test site page speed. Basically it loads a page, checks an element is visible and then logs the time taken between these two events.

I use this to check that the element is visible:

```
def wait_for_visibility(selector, timeout_seconds=10):
retries = timeout_seconds
while retries:
    try:
        element = browser.find_element_by_css_selector(selector)
        if element is not None:
            return element
    except:
        if retries <= 0:
            raise
        else:
            pass

    retries = retries - 1
raise Exception(
    "Element %s not visible despite waiting for %s seconds" % (
        selector, timeout_seconds)
)
```

And I use this order:

```
    test_times['page_pre_' + name] = time.time()

    browser.get(base + path)

    wait_for_visibility(selector=selector_dict[page], timeout_seconds=240)

    test_times['page_post_' + name] = time.time()
```

My issue is that the find_element_by_css_selector doesn't seem to finish & return until a few seconds after the page (and more specifically the element it is supposed to look for) is already finished loading. This is really reducing my script's effectiveness as a speedtest.

The page in question is quite large and is built using Vue components, if that is what it causing the issue then are there any alternative ways I can look out for specific pageload events with selenium?

Comment: Set the capability [`"pageLoadingStrategy": "eager"`](https://www.w3.org/TR/webdriver/#navigation)

Answer (score 0):

I managed to solve that issue checking for elements that havent loaded before without using my own loops but with expected_conditions, here is the code I use

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.common.exceptions import TimeoutException
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
```

...

```
try:
    element_present = EC.presence_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, string))
    WebDriverWait(driver, timeout).until(element_present)
    return driver.find_elements_by_css_selector(string)
except TimeoutException:
    print "Timed out waiting for page to load"
    driver.quit()
```

Basically you specify a timeout in seconds, and expected_conditions will make the WebDriver wait until the expected condition is met or the time is up. In my case this was faster than my own wait wait for element function, it might speed up your script